# send value from one activity to another

Tags: android

I have made the code and there's no error, but *logcat* shows a `NullPointerException`. This is my code to pass and to catch the value from each activity. Please help me solve this.

First activity:

```
try {
    Intent in = new Intent();
    in.setClass(p_daftar_pelanggan.this, ubah_data_pelanggan.class);
    in.putExtra("id", eid.getText().toString());
    in.putExtra("nama", tnama.getText().toString());
    in.putExtra("alamat", ealamat.getText().toString());
    in.putExtra("no_hp", ehp.getText().toString());
    startActivity(in);
}
catch(NullPointerException ex)
{
}
```

Second activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String idpgu = b.getString("id");
String namapgu = b.getString("nama");
String alamatpgu = b.getString("alamat");
String hppgu = b.getString("no_hp");

idp.setText(idpgu);
idp.setKeyListener(null);

nama.setText(namapgu);
ealamat.setText(alamatpgu);
hp.setText(hppgu);
```

Comment: You would need to post the stacktrace. You also shouldn't leave `catch` blocks empty

Comment: @YRO probably you need validate that the values that you are receiving aren´t null, see my answer. Also i recommed post your messages displayed  in LogCat, very important to determinate the source of this exception.

Comment: @Elenasys oke, i'll try.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar yep, i know its duplicate but i still have no answer from that's page

Comment: @codeMagic thanks, i forgot to write down the catch statement

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the second activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String idpgu = intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You put extras using Intent in FirstActivity But Use Bundle to receive it, that is why you have NullPointerException  because SecondActivity is looking for values in different place. 
 Do the following in your secondActvity

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String idpgu = intent.getStringExtra("id");
String namapgu = intent.getStringExtra("nama");
String alamatpgu = intent.getStringExtra("alamat");
String hppgu = intent.getStringExtra("no_hp");
// Check Null for each Values e.g. 
  if (idpgu.trim().equals(" ")) 
{ idpgu = "null"; 
}
```

Comment: is getString can be use to catch value ? i think is not

Comment: See my edit answer. Besides what is the work of this  in.setClass(p_daftar_pelanggan.this, ubah_data_pelanggan.class);? Remove it, clean, build and run the app again

Comment: setClass makes move to second activity.
your suggestion is still not working

Comment: You seem to be passing null value(s) into the putExtra. Try this, in the secondActivity, use if to check if any of the value is null. E.g. if (idpgu.equals("") || idpgu == null) idpgu = "null"; Let me know if it work or want me to update my answer.

Comment: Do Null check in Both Activities

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bundle for this purpose:

```
Activity destActivity = new Activty();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
destActivity.putString("TAG_ForValue",YourValue.getText().toString());
destActivity.setArguments(b);

Intent intent = new Intent(startActivity.this, destActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your destActivity :

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();

if(bundle !=null)
   String value =  bundle.getString("TAG_ForValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending and receiving the values correctly,  but probably some values are null, you can validate setting an empty string instead of a null value:

```
   Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
   String idpgu = (b.getString("id") != null)? b.getString("id") : "";
   String namapgu = (b.getString("nama") != null)? b.getString("nama") : "";
   String alamatpgu = (b.getString("alamat") != null)? b.getString("alamat") : "";
   String hppgu = (b.getString("no_hp") != null)? b.getString("no_hp") : "";
```

Comment: ok post your message displayed in LogCat, probably some of your TextViews is null

Comment: thanks for your help Elen. i have solved my problem. it's my own silly mistake, i called the wrong xml file. hiks, poor me.